# Is tabbing code, to allign it, a good pratice to write nicer code?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am doing the Meteor.js tutorial and this thing got my attention. I am kinda new to coding and I do not want to start in the wrong.

For me, it seems that tabing the info from some lines to make it alligned is far prettier than not doing. And I am wondering if it is good practice to do so.

EXAMPLES

Non-tabbed:

```
export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        tasks: Tasks.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch(),
        incompleteCount: Tasks.find({ checked: { $ne: true } }).count(),
        currentUser: Meteor.user(),
    };
}, App);
```

Tabbed (seems nicer to me):

```
export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        tasks:              Tasks.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch(),
        incompleteCount:    Tasks.find({ checked: { $ne: true } }).count(),
        currentUser:        Meteor.user(),
    };
}, App);
```

Comment: It is a matter of personal preference and coding style. Some teams and languages enforce a certain style, and node.js have their own style guide.

Comment: I am just regurgitating what others have said here, but it's a matter of personal tastes. As you grow as a developer, you will (hopefully) start developing your own style: Tabs instead of spaces, 2 spaces vs 4 spaces, etc.  Some will be dictated by the language, some maybe by the team your work with.  For me, the most important thing is to remain consistent, not only with yourself but also with those you are on a team with.  It kills productivity when a team doesn't use consistent styles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Do we need to align?

If those were actually aligned in some perfect way, what kind of task should be done easier for a developer reading the code?

For example, do we need to look at some two or more lines at the same time to compare them?

Why would we need to compare those lines at all?

```
tasks (a colection)
incompleteCount (a number)
currentUser (an object)
```

I can't find one such example, so my conclusion is: 
No need to compare - no need to align.

### Is there such thing as *aligned*?

Now if you find a reason to align this piece of code with tabs, let's look at the *aligned* version and try to see if it's actually aligned in some useful way.

It turns out it only looks like a more structured code at first.

The fact that the method names are aligned for the Tasks object does not add much to the overall readability - it's not even aligned with the third line in this example:

```
| <- this is the last column that is aligned
|Tasks.|
|Tasks.|
|Meteor.| <- // not aligned anymore, shift one character.
```

So, the tabs structure already started to break at this point.

Now, if you look at the rest of the lines, you will probably find that things do not get aligned. Let's chop the left column of our visual structure and take a look at the right column of the tabbed variant alone:

```
... .find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch(),
... .find({ checked: { $ne: true } }).count(),
...  .user(),
```

If you ask me, it's a mess if I try to perceive it as a whole, and tabs do not help here.

### What implications does this kind of alignment have?

#### Requires unnecessary effort

This is the most annoying one. This kind of alignment is not well supported by the automated formatting tools in the IDEs. In fact you will be probably fighting with your IDE to keep this formatting up to date any time you touch those lines.

#### Can interfere with version control.

Yes, you can probably turn some kind of *ignore witespace* feature in your various version control workflows, but again - there us an overhead to have it.

#### Inconsistent by design

The code is not set in stone, it's evolving. If you add something later it could break the alignment in the unrelated lines.

```
tasks:          |
incompleteCount |
currentUser     |
someOtherMethodAddedLater | <- the first three have to keep up with this one
```

Another point of inconsistency is that the character width is not constant in all fonts, as somebody could think.

There are monospace and non-monospace fonts, and decorating with tabs would only work with monospace fonts. If you use a non-monospace font in the IDE, your tab layout would brake, because any whitespace after a non-whitespace character in a line would not have a property of having a determined position in the viewport.

#### Not a visual cue, quite the contrary!

Try to look up the line on the right corresponding to the property name:
`a4`, without selecting the source code with the mouse.

```
aa:                                    Methods.methodY(453),
ab:                                    Methods.methodZ(554),
a1:                                    Methods.methodX(143),
a2:                                    Methods.methodZ(235),
a3:                                    Methods.methodY(223),
a4:                                    Methods.methodY(334),
a5:                                    Methods.methodY(445),
a6:                                    Methods.methodZ(554),
a7:                                    Methods.methodX(734),
a11:                                   Methods.methodX(143),
a12:                                   Methods.methodZ(235),
a13:                                   Methods.methodY(735),
```

The problem is that with witespace, it's not so easy to match the items on the left and on the right without horizontal grid lines.

The same happens when you try to format code with tabs.

This is not a problem in a text without whitespace, because the non-witespace characters make up a visual link for the entire line of text. For example, in this text it's not a problem for the eye to group words by lines.

So while it could at first appear as a more organized when you look at the page of code as a visual pattern, it's actually less visually linked and is more difficult to read.

So, while using tabs is a practice to make pages of code somewhat visually appealing, the answer is - no, it's not a good practice.

Comment: Very complete answer. The code only looks "nicer", but it is not a practical thing to do. Thanks.

Comment: OP's alignment visually separates object properties from implementation details and thus reflects a separation of interface VS implementation. So while I agree with your conclusion, your answer could be better by being more objective.

Comment: @le_m good observation. I will consider improving my answer taking this into account, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I like your style too.  But how easy will it be to maintain when you change the names of the properties (or rename them automatically in and IDE).

I think the main reason people don't use this style is because it's impossible (very difficult) to maintain.

If you share your code, others may not have the same tab setting and it won't look pretty to them at all.

If it's just your own code, format it how ever you like.  Your style is very readable, but you may find it difficult to maintain.

Comment: I agree with you. In classes, code I made on Notepad++ looked out of place once I copied into the IDE

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer as objectively as possible, since this is a Q & A site and not suited for opinionated debate:

Tabbing - PRO:

- Visual cue, arguably faster visual parsing of keys and values

Tabbing - CONTRA:

- Tab width is editor dependent, a different tab width might ruin the alignment
- Adding or removing keys might require editing all the other values' indentation

I have seen such indentation used in small / static code snippets whose main purpose is to facilitate understanding / teaching. I rarely see such indentation used in productive code which is subject to frequent changes or refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start getting on a large team there is a *huge* difference in the styles...

If you add or remove a key from that list you then have to reformat a number of lines.

When I'm going through version control trying to figure out what changes are made to the file, It will be littered with various white-space changes that I then have to examine to see if they matter.

Keep the clutter down!

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated, it depends on your own preference. Something to know is that you don't necessarily have to do the tabbing yourself. You could just write code and then use some resource like [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) or a local reindenter in your text editor .